# Max File Extension Length

Tags: asp.net, file-io

Is there a maximum lengh for a file extension?  The longest one I've seen is .compiled (8 chars)

**Useless Background**

I'm creating a IHttpHandler to return image icons for a specific filename.  I'm simply calling a FileImage.axd?ext=pptx.  I'm generating the files on the fly using SHGetFileInfo similar to [my post](http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/nativefiletypeviewer-fileiconimageconverter-convert-a-filename-to-the-file-system-icon/) for WPF, then caching them locally in a folder with the filename 'pptx.png'.  I'd like to validate the length and trim it to prevent a DoS type attack where someone would try to generate images for and infinite number of junk characters (eg FileImage.axd?ext=asdfasdfweqrsadfasdfwqe...).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no limit, except the maximum length of the file name. Extension is not treated specially except in FAT16.

Comment: Thanks this unfortunately doesn't give me a solution.  I guess I'll just limit it to 10.  The images are going to be loaded from the webserver, so i wonder what the longest extension on a stardard build of IIS webserver would be.

Comment: The solution is - write your code so that it can work with any extension size, avoid C Programmer's Disease.

Comment: [C Programmer's Disease](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/C-Programmers-Disease.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Arkadiy - there is no formal limit now that the DOS 8.3 system is a thing of the past (or other similar, limited systems).  I would say that the majority of the extensions I've seen are in the range 1-3; Java uses 4 for .java and 5 for .class.  Your example with 8 is longer than I recall.  If I were scoping, I'd aim for 'unlimited'; if that's not feasible, allow at least 16 characters - with the confident expectation that in fact 16 would be quite sufficient for current systems.

Comment: If this is ever applied in Unix environment, files like .profile may have names longer than 16, and of course the entire name is an extension :)

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of extension.  I wouldn't count it as an extension unless there is something before the dot, but the alternative viewpoint is also logically tenable.  Also, those extensions are all unique - you can't have 16 files all called .profile in a single directory.